# How can I change an image upon clicking using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having some trouble changing one image to another with Javascript. Ideally, the program should change the image upon being clicked, but I believe the syntax of the command is incorrect. My images are in a folder called "images" and the program files are found in the same folder as the "images" folder. The error I've noticed is that, when clicked, the image attempts to change, but there is an error with changing the source image.

I've read similar questions, but the answers were over my head, as far as complexity goes. I was reading an example of what I wanted to do, but I can't get my code to work, even though I practically copied the whole code.

**Javascript**

```
function changeIMG() {
var image = document.getElementById("face");
    if (image.src.match("off")) {
        image.src = "images\on.png";
    } else {
        image.src = "images\off.png";
    }}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>

<center>
<h3>Welcome to the game.</h3>

<br>



<img src="images\off.png" id="face" onClick="changeIMG()" height="250" width="250">



</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `images/on.png";` instead of `images\on.png";`

your javascript function is working well.

```js
function changeIMG() {
var image = document.getElementById("face");
    if (image.src.match("off")) {
        image.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=on";
    } else {
        image.src = "http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=off";
    }}
```

```html
<center>
<h3>Welcome to the game.</h3>
<br>
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=off" id="face" onClick="changeIMG()" height="250" width="250">
</center>
```

Comment: This worked well. It was an unfortunate error that I didn't catch.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of my previous projects of changing images:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var btnvalue
    $("#next").click(function(){
        btnvalue = $( this ).attr( "data-dir" );
       if (btnvalue == 1)
       {
                $( this ).attr( "data-dir","2")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image2").slideDown();
       }
       if (btnvalue == 2)
       {
                $( this ).attr( "data-dir","3")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(3)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image3").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
       if (btnvalue == 3)
       {
                $( this ).attr( "data-dir","4")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(3)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image4").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
       if (btnvalue == 4)
       {
                $( this ).attr( "data-dir","1")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image1").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
    })
// Previous
    $("#prev").click(function(){
         btnvalue = $("#next").attr( "data-dir" );
       if (btnvalue == 2)
       {
                $("#next").attr( "data-dir","1")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image1").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
       if (btnvalue == 3)
       {
                $("#next").attr( "data-dir","2")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(3)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(2)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image2").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
       if (btnvalue == 4)
       {
                $("#next").attr( "data-dir","3")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(3)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image3").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
       if (btnvalue == 1)
       {
                $("#next").attr( "data-dir","4")
                $( "ul li:nth-child(1)" ).css(                                "display", "none" );
                $( "ul li:nth-child(4)" ).css(                                "display", "block" );
                $("#image4").slideDown( 1000, function() {
                 // Animation complete
                
                });
       }
    })
  
})
```

```css
button{
    height : 17px;
    width : 60px;
    
}
#slider-nav{
 color : red;
padding-top : 0em;

  
}
#next{
 background-color : red;   
    
}
#prev{
 background-color : yellow;   
    
}
.slider{
 width : inherit;
 height : 300px;
 overflow : hidden
}
.slider ul{
 width : 10000px;
 list-style : none;
    
}
.slider li {
 float : left   
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(1){
   position:absolute;
     width:600px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    
    
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(2){
   position:absolute;
     width:600px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    
    
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(3){
   position:absolute;
     width:600px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    
    
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(4){
   position:absolute;
     width:600px;
     height:200px;
     z-index:15;
     top:50%;
     left:50%;
     margin:-100px 0 0 -150px;
    
    
}

.slider ul li:nth-child(2){
    display : none
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(3){
    display : none
}
.slider ul li:nth-child(4){
    display : none
}
.slider {
 border : 2px solid   
}

body{
 width : 600px
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <script src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div class = "slider">
<ul>
    <li>
        <!-- You can change this images if you want in a seperate document by forking my begginer progect-->
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQdJA38xKrGuTdclgbe0-zgfEaiJELl9nVWH2vGTi4PeRhnLW6EiQ" style="border-style: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -25px;" id = "image1">
    </li>
    
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSiXFcdb29GcvK2CmKx07wuU07Ceiwwwqp9Uth1fUZovELuGVqDNnPR9A" style="border-style: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -25px;" id = "image2">
    </li>
    
    <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR8o6qWq__fEP1-HaIEc28-vl1YWPyKgP0FxewzfK5PYCcgUo23Ba0M4gs" style="border-style: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -25px;" id = "image3">
    </li>
   
     <li>
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQfPNnAdm3ejpo5SE6r4Sd9Y0icOCscELCrs8RWSpLCb76sQ5bATzydvw" style="border-style: none; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin-left: -25px;margin-top: -25px;" id = "image4">
    </li>
</ul>
    
    
    
    </div>
    <div id = "slider-nav">
       <button data-dir ="prev" id = "prev">previous</button>
        <button id = "next" data-dir = "1" >next</button>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not great with the whole HTML5 stuff, but this acts like a slideshow, right? That would be an interesting concept I would like to try, but not exactly what I was looking for in this program.

Comment: @SyntaxError_autumn if you found this anwser most helpfull, dont forget to award best anwser :-)